# Pandas: frequencies per date grouped by column in a form of a list

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to obtain frequencies of technologies per date from pandas data frame. A reproducible example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
        {'dates': ['2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-02-28'],
        'tech': [['c++', 'python'], ['c++', 'c', 'java'], ['java']]}
        )
```

The end result could look like this (or have the names in rows and one column with counts per date and technology):

```
date        c++     python  c   java
2017-01-31  1       1       0   0
2017-02-28  1       0       1   2
```

The second column, by which the data should be grouped is a list of technologies. Simply trying to group by the data in the present state:

```
data.groupby(['dates', data.tech.values]).count()
```

produces an error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

so I presume that grouping by list is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(data.set_index('dates').tech.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
Out[193]: 
            c  c++  java  python
dates                           
2017-01-31  0    1     0       1
2017-02-28  1    1     2       0
```

Or `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(data.tech), data.dates, mlb.classes_).sum(level=0)
Out[209]: 
            c  c++  java  python
dates                           
2017-01-31  0    1     0       1
2017-02-28  1    1     2       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(data['tech'].values.tolist(), index=data['dates'].values)
         .stack()
         .groupby(level=0)
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         )

print (df1)
            c  c++  java  python
2017-01-31  0    1     0       1
2017-02-28  1    1     2       0
```

**Explanation**:

First create new DataFrame by contructor from `lists`:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(data['tech'].values.tolist(), index=data['dates'].values))
               0       1     2
2017-01-31   c++  python  None
2017-02-28   c++       c  java
2017-02-28  java    None  None
```

Then reshape to `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(data['tech'].values.tolist(), index=data['dates'].values)
         .stack()
         )

print (df1)
2017-01-31  0       c++
            1    python
2017-02-28  0       c++
            1         c
            2      java
            0      java
dtype: object
```

Get counts per groups by firstl level by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(data['tech'].values.tolist(), index=data['dates'].values)
         .stack()
         .groupby(level=0)
         .value_counts()

         )

print (df1)
2017-01-31  c++       1
            python    1
2017-02-28  java      2
            c         1
            c++       1
dtype: int64
```

Last reshape to final `DataFrame` by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(data['tech'].values.tolist(), index=data['dates'].values)
         .stack()
         .groupby(level=0)
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         )

print (df1)
            c  c++  java  python
2017-01-31  0    1     0       1
2017-02-28  1    1     2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing answers provided by @Wen and @jezrael (thanks a lot!) I decided to check the performance of the suggested solutions by wrapping the consecutive approaches into functions:

## Dataset

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
        {'dates': ['2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-02-28'],
        'tech': [['c++', 'python'], ['c++', 'c', 'java'], ['java']]}
        )
```

## First solution - dummies

```
def first():
    pd.get_dummies(data.set_index('dates').tech.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level = 0)
```

## Second solution - sklearn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

def second():
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(data.tech), data.dates, mlb.classes_).sum(level = 0)
```

## Third solution - tolist()

```
def third():
    (pd.DataFrame(data['tech'].values.tolist(), index = data['dates'].values)
    .stack()
    .groupby(level = 0)
    .value_counts()
    .unstack(fill_value = 0))
```

## Performance comparison

```
%timeit first()   # 4.86 ms ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit second()  # 2.09 ms ± 29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit third()   # 3.66 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

## Summary

To sum up, all the proposed approaches brought the same result. In terms of execution time, the fastest one was the second solution, which takes advantage of `MultiLabelBinarizer` function imported from `sklearn`.